# How to map join classes in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping

I want to map the classes Node, Unit and Module to do this select:

```
select n.nid, n.nnm, n.nhwtype, u.unnr, u.unhwtype, u.unslot, m.mpos, m.mhwtype from node n, unit u, module m where n.nid*=u.nid and n.nid*=m.nid and u.nid*=m.nid and u.unnr*=m.unnr and n.nhwtype in (10020, 10021, 10022, 10023, 10002, 10017, 10001) and m.mpos not between 11 and 10000
```

(ONE) Node -> Unit (MANY)

(ONE) Unit -> Module (MANY)

I tried so many times, but I didnt have success.

Comment: And what did you try? Post your best JPQL query attempt.

Comment: You could use this tutorial http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example/